# How can I install stmfpt package in Stata?

Tags: stata

I want to install `stmfpt` package in Stata.

I write this command

```
ssc install stmfpt
```

But it's not installed. I see this code

```
. ssc install  stmfpt
  ssc install: "stmfpt" not found at SSC, type -findit stmfpt-
  (To find all packages at SSC that start with s, type -ssc describe s-)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please try to use basic documentation, notably help for each command.

Comment: As said: it's not on SSC. So, `ssc install` will fail. I've already given different commands.

Answer (score 1):

The information you give underlines that

The package is not on SSC. That explains why you cannot install it from there.

It is posted elsewhere.

The following commands worked for me.

```
net from http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucakjpr/stata
net install stmfpt
```

Comment: Show us exactly what you typed and what Stata typed in return. (Edit your question with those details.)